# Select All as default value for Multivalue parameter

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, parameters

I'm building a report in Visual Studio 2008 with a lot of [multivalue parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337292%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) and it's working great, but I would like to have have the "(Select all)" option as the default value when the report is opened.

Is there some kind of expression or SQL code I can use to make this happen? Or do I need to choose "(Select all)" every time, in every parameter, each time I want to run the report?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Try setting the parameters' "default value" to use the same query as the "available values". In effect it provides every single "available value" as a "default value" and the "Select All" option is automatically checked.

Comment: Thanks a ton. Only thing to add is; if the query you are using for "available values" returns any null values, you can't set the default value to "(select all"), probably because the multivalue function doesn't allow nulls. 
Anyway thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: Still see a bug with SSRS 2008 R2, the cascading dropdown does not check all if parant dropdown all values are checked after 2 , 3 round of check and uncheck.

Comment: @iljitj The NULL value thing was burning me and had me stumped - thanks for this nugget!

Comment: I was sure I didn't have null values, and almost moved on in my research on this, but double checked, and sure enough, I had nulls sometimes, depending on previous parameter selections. Mentioning it here, hoping it saves the next person a few minutes of frustration. Always try a few different combinations of a query before making assumptions about the consistently of your results. Thanks @iljitj.

Comment: Great, @jcford. Thanks! Just want to add that it's simple to implement "some, not all, as defaults" by embedding business rules in a clone of the source dataset that returns just the values you want selected. e.g. If the complete list of possibilities contains A,B, and C, and the dataset is called AvailOptions, you could add a boolean column called [Default] and then have a second dataset called AvailOptionsJustDefault that has a Where clause of Default = 1.

Answer (score 20):

Using dataset with default values is one way, but you must use query for Available values and for Default Values, if values are hard coded in Available values tab, then you must define default values as expressions. Pictures should explain everything

Create Parameter (if not automaticly created)

[image: Create Parameter]

Define values - wrong way example

[image: Define values - wrong way]

Define values - correct way example

[image: Define values - correct way]

Set default values - you must define all default values reflecting available values to make "Select All" by default, if you won't define all only those defined will be selected by default.

[image: Set default values]

The Result

[image: The result]

One picture for Data type: Int

[image: One picture for Data type Int]

Comment: The images got down sized, sorry, I hope you can read comments on them.

Comment: You mention "*then you must define default values as expressions*" but you do not explain *why* one should do this.  I am curious as to why this is necessary?

Comment: It was self discovery back then. Don't really know, but I suspect expressions (in this case) are programmatic values, so the engine knows what type they are. If you enter just Value it doesn't know if it's string or int, and can't do multi-select. But other than that I don't know the reason, I just know it work that way. Feel free to research :)

Comment: The engine knows what data type it is from your selection in the `Data Type:` option on the `General` properties screen.  The parameter can only hold values of that data type regardless of what you enter in as an expression.

Comment: I was trying to make the best guess. Anything like that feel free to call Microsoft they have bugs everywhere I even had to fix reporting engine to render correctly in Chrome. They are bunch of lame people using IE, anything is possible with them

Answer (score 9):

Does not work if you have nulls.

You can get around this by modifying your select statement to plop something into nulls:

```
phonenumber = CASE
  WHEN (isnull(phonenumber, '')='') THEN '(blank)'
  ELSE phonenumber
END
```

Comment: does that symbol mean something or are you outputting a sadface

Comment: ssrs always makes me output a sad face

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer is *correct*, but **not complete**.
In order for `Select All` to be the default option, the Available Values dataset must contain at least 2 columns: value and label. They can return the same data, but their names have to be different. The Default Values dataset will then use value column and then `Select All` will be the default value. If the dataset returns only 1 column, only the last record's value will be selected in the drop down of the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answer from E_8.
This does not work if you have empty strings.

You can get around this by modifying your select statement in SQL or modifying your query in the SSRS dataset.

```
 Select distinct phonenumber
from YourTable
where phonenumber <> ''
Order by Phonenumber
```

Answer (score 0):

It works better

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T_Status](
   [Status] [nvarchar](20) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
INSERT [dbo].[T_Status] ([Status]) VALUES (N'Active')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[T_Status] ([Status]) VALUES (N'notActive')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[T_Status] ([Status]) VALUES (N'Active')
GO

DECLARE @GetStatus nvarchar(20) = null
--DECLARE @GetStatus nvarchar(20) = 'Active'
SELECT [Status]
FROM [T_Status]
WHERE  [Status] = CASE WHEN (isnull(@GetStatus, '')='') THEN [Status]
ELSE @GetStatus END
```

Answer (score -4):

This is rather easy to achieve by making a dataset with a text-query like this:

```
SELECT 'Item1'
UNION
SELECT 'Item2'
UNION
SELECT 'Item3'
UNION
SELECT 'Item4'
UNION
SELECT 'ItemN'
```

The query should return all items that can be selected.