# multivalued parameters in SSRS - selecting only one value

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I've set up a report with a multi-valued parameter. The dataset is essentially

```
select 'Abc' as field1
Union all
select 'lmnop'
union all
select 'xyz'
order by Field1
```

Available values - Label and Value are both set to Field1 
Default values - Value is set to Field1

I would expect only the 'Abc' to be selected by default and the rest unselected. But instead, I'm seeing all of them selected. This works as expected with single valued parameters.

SSRS 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

Based on this answer and some quick testing, it seems that when a parameter is defined as multi-value *and* there is no NULL in the dataset, the default behaviour is to select all of them. Otherwise, it selects None. [Select All as default value for Multivalue parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508910/select-all-as-default-value-for-multiple-values-parameter-ssrs)

Which makes sense, I suppose, from a behaviour perspective. You're allowing multi-select so why not assume someone will start with everything selected? Seems as arbitrary as expecting the first thing to be selected.

Answer (score 0):

Got it, whatever is returned from the default values dataset will become selected when the report is run.

So if I have as Dataset for Available option

```
select 'a' as field1
union all
select 'b'
union all
select 'c'
```

and I have as Dataset2 for Default option

```
Select 'b' as selectedField
```

Then, *only* 'B' will be selected by default when the report is run. Makes sense.