# How do I set a Default Value of "Select All" in SSRS?

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Select All as default value for Multivalue parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508910/select-all-as-default-value-for-multivalue-parameter)

I have a drop-down parameter in SSRS that gets populated via the following query:

```
select ID, name from accounts where LK_RecordStatusID = 1 order by Name asc
```

I need it to be a multi-value parameter. In SSRS, I can do this. However, I can't also let it be a null value . However, I'd like it to have a default-value of "Null", that corresponds to the "Select All" choice.

I looked online and I see something about using -1 as an alternative to null? It seems I can't specify a null value . Any tips appreciated, thanks

[image]

Comment: @Jeroen - Indeed, this is a duplicate . Thank You!! I found answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/2547762/763029

Comment: Aight, good to hear you solved it. Note that you can mark your own question as a duplicate by clicking the "close(#)" link below the tags. This helps others that land here with a search find the related question (and answer) quickly.

Comment: This one helped me more than the other post.

Comment: @crh225 - You mean this ? -  [Select All as default value for Multivalue parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508910/select-all-as-default-value-for-multivalue-parameter)

Comment: @Coffee - this post helped me more than any other post.

Answer (score 7):

With the help of [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2547762/763029), I got this fixed (thanks Jeroen) ,  just needed to make the "Default Values" the same as Available val.'s:

[image]